# Реализация протокола общения с фискальным принтером

Tags: c#, com-порт, protocol

Предстоит реализовать протокол для фискального термо-принтера ([FP-550F](http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/45)). Вроде с КОМ-портом есть небольшой опыт, однако споткнулся там где не ожидал, а именно составление сообщения для отправки принтеру через КОМ-порт - текст должен имеет следующий формат:

```
 <01><LEN><SEQ><CMD><DATA><05><BCC><03>
```

в частности где:

```
<01> - вводная часть, 1 байт - значение 01H
<LEN> - количество байтов с <01> (исключенный) до <05> (включенный), плюс смещение на 20H, 1 байт
<SEQ> - идентификатор сообщения, 1 байт
<CMD> - комманда, значение из 20H-7FH, 1 байт
<DATA> - параметры команды 
<05> - идентификатор конца, 1 байт - значение 05H
<BCC> - контрольная сумма - текст из документа - The sum includes between <01> preamble (excluded) to <05>. Each digit from the two bytes is sent after 30H is added to it. For example the sum 1AE3H is presented as 31H, 3AH, 3EH, 33H.
<03> - терминатор, 1 байт - значение 03H
```

Так как пишу на С#, то использую обертку `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`, но так порту отправляется текстовое значение, то непонятно как собрать само сообщение:

1. значения `<01>`,`<05>` и `<03>` - это один символ?
2. значение для `<LEN>` - как определить длину значения, где одна составляющая часть. а именно `<LEN>` - не известна? и потом это перевести в строку? не понимаю выражение "смещение на 20H" - это битовая операция?
3. контрольная сумма - как её вычислить?

Есть у кого опыт с этим? Можете помочь?

Comment: Кто вам сказал что порту отправляется текстовое значение?

Comment: "<03> - это один символ?" - нет, это один байт, что явно написано в процитированной документации. "<LEN> - не известна?" - опять неверно, явно написано что она 1 байт. Смещение - непонятно что, но вероятно подразумевалось +0x20

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов т.е. значение будет длина команды+длина параметров, со смещением 20H ?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write("Command");'

Comment: @dreadangel Длина, вероятно, будет 0x24 + длина DATA. Но надо проверить на приведенных в документации примерах.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вот именно что примеров нету, увы...

Comment: @dreadangel одна беда, не умеет ком-порт "текстовые значения" слать, шлет он исключительно байты... А если примеров нет - цепляться к проводу и смотреть на реальный обмен, или пробовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69854/discussion-between-dreadangel-and--).

Comment: Пролистал доки... Вы уверены что он в Ascii режиме работает?

Comment: @Vasek вроде должно...

Comment: Мне непонятно как именно собрать сообщение для отправки через ком порт. Понял что нужно собрать в форме массива байт. Но составляющие - а именно значение для <LEN> и <BCC>. Увы отсуствует опыт...

Comment: У них демо программу нет?

Comment: есть - но через COM-обьект... я же хочу написать свой драйвер...

Comment: @dreadangel ответил в чате